# PHP parse by class

Tags: php, html-parsing

I want parse this code, this is the html:

```html
<div class="fila">
 <div class="ver_categoria">
  <a href="/cat/5/" >Series</a>
 </div>
 <div class="ver_file">
  <strong><a href="/descargas/120849" title=" Crimen" class="menu_link">Crimen</a></strong>
 </div>
 <div class="ver_date">114 sems</div>
 <div class="ver_uploader">T - D - G</div>
 <div class="ver_size">334 MB</div>
 <div class="ver_seeds"><strong>9</strong></div>
 <div class="ver_peers"><strong>1</strong></div>
</div>
```

The result shows a first line that I don´t want to see..

```html
<?php $url= $torrent;

$html = file_get_contents($url);
$html = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'iso-8859-1');
 $doc = new DOMDocument();
  $doc->loadHTML($html);

  $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
  $articles = $xpath->query('//*[@class="fila"]');
   foreach($articles as $item) {
 $cols = $item->getElementsByTagName("div");
 $tipo = $cols->item(0)->nodeValue;
 $direc = $cols->item(1)->nodeType === XML_ELEMENT_NODE ? $cols->item(1)->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)->getAttribute('href') : '';
 $direcci = str_replace("/","",$direc);
 $direccion= str_replace("descargar","id=",$direcci);
 $enlace = $cols->item(1)->nodeValue;
 $tiempo = $cols->item(2)->nodeValue;
 $amo = $cols->item(3)->nodeValue;
 $tamano = $cols->item(4)->nodeValue;
 $seeds = $cols->item(5)->nodeValue;
 $peers = $cols->item(6)->nodeValue;
 
 echo ''.$tipo.' '.$direccion.' '.$enlace.' '.$tiempo.' '.$amo.' '.$tamano.' '.$seeds.' '.$peers.'</br>';
  };
?>
```

The code rus perfecty, but any idea for avoid the first line in the result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Comment: What did you try? What happened (`does not work` doesnt tell us much)?

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Thanks in advance, I've already show my code.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong except the `;` after the closing curly brackets. Also, you can make it shorter using a more elaborated XPath query: `//*[@class="filo"]//a`

Comment: What is this `</H4>` ? Other thing, are you sure a `preg_replace` is needed? A simple `trim` doesn't suffice?

Comment: Thanks @Casimir-et-Hippolite, I can find a semi-solution.. You can see my new code